# PHP Form / Upload de arquivo e envio de outros campos de uma vez

Tags: php, webforms

**Como realizar o upload de um arquivo e enviar os demais dados do form em uma unica ação?**
Tenho (como exemplo) o seguinte formulário:

```
<form method="POST" name="form" action="ccd.php">
    <input value="" type="text" id="nome" name="nome"/>
    <input value="" type="text" id="modelo" name="modelo"/>
    <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto"/>
</form>
```

Porém quando adiciono o **enctype** de "multipart/form-data", para passar os dados do arquivo para o **ccd.php**, ele não envia os dados de *nome* e *modelo*.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" name="form">
```

Quando removo o **enctype** de "multipart/form-data", ele passa os dados de *nome* e *modelo*, porém não passa os dados do arquivo.

```
$uploaddir = "../fotos";

if (isset($_POST['foto'])){
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['foto']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile){}
}
```

E recebo o erro:

```
Notice: Undefined index: foto in /media/[...]/ccd.php on line 31
```

Comment: uma coisa que está na pergunta não corresponde a realidade tem que utilizar o `enctype`,mas, você olha para pergunta, cade os itens que você diz que não carrega? Qual é a linha 31? falta complementar sua pergunta !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reparei que falta fechar um parêntesis nesta linha

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {}
```

Além disso o conteúdo do ficheiro é colocado no array `$_FILES`. Como fazes `if (isset($_POST['foto'])){` nunca irá executar.

O `enctype="multipart/form-data"` é obrigatório neste caso.